# If Column from Group of Rows Contains 'x' Return 'x' for All Related Rows in New column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the table below and I want to create a new column which looks at the [**Registration Date**] and the [**Person ID**] and checks all the values in [**Registration Status**], if the [**Person ID**] has 1 or more ‘Present’ or 1 or more ‘Not Registered’ within a day then they are present for the whole day, otherwise they are absent.

As an example (*Highlighted red in image below*), look at the 7th Feb 2022 where **Person ID = 103**. He has 4 rows of ‘Not Registered’ resulting in 'Present' for the day:

**The granularity of the rows needs to stay the same** so Group By wouldn’t work in this instance.

Thank you in advance.

```
Register ID Person ID   Registration Date   Registration Time   Registration Status Desired Output
1   100 07-Feb-22   07:30:00    Present Present
2   100 07-Feb-22   08:00:00    Not Registered  Present
2   100 07-Feb-22   08:55:00    Absent  Present
2   100 07-Feb-22   10:10:00    Present Present
3   101 07-Feb-22   07:30:00    Not Registered  Present
3   101 07-Feb-22   07:40:00    Absent  Present
3   101 07-Feb-22   08:25:00    Absent  Present
3   101 07-Feb-22   09:10:00    Present Present
5   102 07-Feb-22   07:30:00    Absent  Absent
5   102 07-Feb-22   12:00:00    Absent  Absent
2   103 07-Feb-22   07:30:00    Not Registered  Present
2   103 07-Feb-22   07:40:00    Not Registered  Present
2   103 07-Feb-22   08:25:00    Not Registered  Present
2   103 07-Feb-22   09:10:00    Not Registered  Present
6   100 08-Feb-22   07:30:00    Absent  Absent
7   100 08-Feb-22   08:00:00    Absent  Absent
8   101 09-Feb-22   07:30:00    Absent  Absent
9   101 09-Feb-22   07:40:00    Absent  Absent
10  101 09-Feb-22   08:25:00    Absent  Absent
11  101 09-Feb-22   09:10:00    Absent  Absent
```

[image]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Sample data (and desired results) needs to be formatted text within the question, not links to offsite resources.

Comment: Hi Dale, when I tried to paste the raw data in (from Excel) it only allowed me to paste it in as in image?

Comment: Don't post links to file sharing sites to share files with users here. The majority of users who will be attempting to answer your questions are subject experts and know the dangers (and foolishness) of downloading a file from an unknown person. Many of us may also be using a work PC, so the danger isn't even greater, and the site may well be blocked anyway, making the link useless. Any information that is important to the questions needs to be included *within* the question. Code should be in code blocks, and data in DDL and DML statements, well formatted tabular `text` or a markdown table.

Comment: Why does person_id = 101 on 07-Feb-2022 have desired status = 'Present'? According to you description it should be 'Absent'.

Comment: Hi All, in the end it was a combination of Erin and Domin0's answers that helped me solve the issue. I took a bit from both and found a solution.

Domin0, Person ID 101 on the 7th should all be present as there is one row 'present'. You were correct about it being a datetime and your CAST fixed the issue, however your count was incorrect as it should have been greater than 0 which I took from Erin.

I feel like you were both as helpful as each other in answering the question. Is it possible to mark both your answers as correct?

Comment: Please don't add an answer to your question by editing it in. If your question has been solved by an answer, you can accept it, if you solved the problem yourself you can [write your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept that.

Answer (score 3):

```
select *, case when count(case when Registration_Status= 'Present' then 1 end) OVER (PARTITION BY person_id, cast(Registration_Date as date)) >= 1
                 or count(case when Registration_Status= 'Not Registered' then 1 end) OVER (PARTITION BY person_id, cast(Registration_Date as date)) >= 1
               then 'Present'
               else 'Absent'
          end
from table
```

Comment: Hi Domin0, I just tested your code and it is not working as expected. It is returning absent   when it should be present.

Comment: I edited my answer just in case Registration_Date was a datetime field. Maybe this is the reason the query didn't return desired result?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **CASE** expression for that.

For your example:

```
SELECT [Register ID],[Person ID],[Registration Date],[Registration Time],[Registration Status]
CASE
    WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN [Registration Status]= 'Present' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY [Person ID], [Registration Date]) > 0 THEN 'Present'
    WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN [Registration Status]= 'Not Registered' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY [Person ID], [Registration Date]) > 0 THEN 'Present'
    ELSE 'Absent'
END AS [Desired Output]
FROM YourTable;
```

should work.

Comment: Hi Eren, thank you for your response, but this does not work on a per day, per person id basis. If you look at person id 101 on the 7th Feb you will get 2 absents in there wheras it should be present based on the logic I've described above.

Comment: Hi @Abraham you're right. I just edited my answer. Can you check that query?

Answer (score 0):

The final answer was a **combination of Erin and Domni0's solutions**.

```
SELECT [registration date],
   [person id],
   CASE
     WHEN Count(CASE
                  WHEN [registrationstatus] = 'Present'
                        OR [registrationstatus] = 'Not Registered' THEN 1
                END)
            OVER (
              partition BY [person id], [registration date]) > 0 THEN
     'Present'
     ELSE 'Absent'
   END AS [Desired Outcome]   FROM Table
```

Thank you both for your help.